# Dropdown Column with Ajax

Tags: datatable, dropdown

I want to create dropdown column from my ajax source but I couldn't get it done I try everything.

http://live.datatables.net/hexidaqi/1/edit

In the example, I tried to have the office column in the dropdown.

Can you help with me this one please :(

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. It sounds like you want to create a drop-down list in every cell of the Office column. And you want all those drop-downs to contain a list of all possible offices. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am trying to do with only office column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a column renderer in the way that you are trying to use it. This renderer only has access to the data in each separate row. It does not have a complete view of all the rows in the table. So it can't see what office data has already been processed, or will be processed.

To work around this, there are 2 approaches that I can think of (and probably more that I cannot think of):

1. Pre-process your ajax JSON so that you have already built a list of the unique office names, and add that to each object in your JSON (or similar) so that this data is now available to your column renderer.
2. Wait until the table has finished being created (with no column renderer and no select lists) - and then build the select lists from the data in the table, and replace the office values with the select lists.

Here is that second approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: "my test URL here - see the JSON data below"
  },
  searching: "false",
  columns: [
    { data: "name" },
    { data: "position" },
    { data: "office" },
    { data: "age" },
    { data: "start_date" },
    { data: "salary" }
  ],
  initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    var officeData = this.api().column(2).data();
    var officeSelect = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>');
    officeData.unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
      officeSelect.append( '<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>' );
    } );
    officeSelect.appendTo( $('table#example tbody td:nth-child(3)').empty() );
  }

} ); 

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

After the table has finished being built, we can access the data in column index 2 (the Office column):

```
var officeData = this.api().column(2).data();
```

We can then process each unique value and create a select list `<option>`:

```
officeData.unique().sort().each( ... );
```

After building the HTML for the select list, we can replace all the Office column's nodes with this new select list:

```
officeSelect.appendTo( $('table#example tbody td:nth-child(3)').empty() );
```

Note that the DataTables column indexing starts at zero, but the jQuery `:nth-child` selector starts at 1 - which is why we have `column(2)` but `td:nth-child(3)`.

This is a basic solution - for example, there aren't any event handlers attached to the select lists. If you want to actually do something useful with selections made by a user, then that would be extra work (and probably a new question).

---

For completeness, here is my source JSON:

```
{ "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "age": "23"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "age": "34"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "age": "45"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "age": "36"
    },
    {
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "age": "42"
    }
] }
```

---

**Update**

Based on the [example](http://live.datatables.net/duzavuzu/1/edit) provided in one of the comments below:

That is a clever approach, but it does seem to be over-complicated for the problem you are trying to solve - and, as you point out, it assumes each value is unique across the entire set of values in the column.

Here is a revised approach which does a couple of new things from my original approach:

1. It operates on DataTable nodes, so that the values are available across all pages.
2. It captures the value provided in the source data and selects that as the "selected" (displayed) value in the drop-down:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: "http://localhost:7000/ajax-employees"
  },
  searching: "false",
  "pageLength": 2, // just for testing multiple pages
  columns: [
    { data: "name" },
    { data: "position" },
    { data: "office" },
    { data: "age" },
    { data: "start_date" },
    { data: "salary" }
  ],
  initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    var officeData = this.api().column(2).data();
    var officeNodes = this.api().column(2).nodes().toArray();
    var officeList = officeData.unique().sort().toArray();

    officeData.each( function ( cellValue, idx ) {
      var options = '';
      officeList.forEach((office) => { 
        console.log( cellValue, office );
        if (office === cellValue) {
            options = options + '<option value="' + office + '" selected>' + office + '</option>';
        } else {
            options = options + '<option value="' + office + '">' + office + '</option>';
        }
        console.log( options );
      } );
      var officeSelect = $('<select>' + options + '</select>');
      officeSelect.appendTo( $(officeNodes[idx]).empty() );
    } );
  }

} ); 

} );
```

By capturing the nodes in the Datatable:

```
this.api().column(2).nodes()
```

...we can build drop-downs for all rows in the table, regardless of pagination.

By comparing the cell's value against the master list of unique offices, we know when to add the `selected` attribute to an `<option>` element.

Comment: I just realized that I wrote this as a snippet - but obviously it won't run as a snippet because it depends on an ajax call, which is not provided. It should have been written as a simple code block instead. That does not affect the answer - it's just that you cannot execute the snippet.

Comment: It's working exactly as I want, thank you so much for your help :)  It's just one more thing can we select the dropdown. Like if the office is Tokyo, Tokyo will be selected.

Comment: And there is a problem, if I jump to next page the dropdown is disappearing
Here is the example http://live.datatables.net/pakakosi/1/edit

Comment: "_if the office is Tokyo, Tokyo will be selected_" - I am sorry - I don't know what you mean.

Comment: "_if I jump to next page the dropdown is disappearing_" - right - that is why I wrote _If you want to actually do something useful with selections made by a user, then that would be extra work (and probably a new question)._

Comment: Understood thank you for your help, at last, this example gives me a starting point.

Comment: Changes made to the HTML table are not automatically saved to the underlying DataTable (the JavaScript object). So, one high-level approach is: (1) add a "change" [event listener](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for each drop-down; (2) when a drop-down is changed, save the entire content of that node (the text of the `<select>` element, with the chosen selection, also) [to the relevant cell](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) in the DataTable. I haven't looked, but I expect these points are covered in existing answers. Or post a new question with your attempt, if you get stuck.

Comment: I find this one it's easy also: http://live.datatables.net/duzavuzu/1/edit
But I don't want multiple same office input. In the example, you can see repeated offices. There is only 6 office so it should have only six office input in the dropdown. If I can find I solution for that it will be awesome :)

Comment: I have added some more notes to my answer. The example you link to is interesting, but I think it's overly complicated for what you actually are trying to do. I have provided an alternative approach.

Comment: You've been helping for a few days. Thank you so much you are the best :) Finally, it is just likes what I want.

Comment: Hi Andrew, can I ask you a question again?
For different table, I prepared another prototype in this link. http://live.datatables.net/jemuciki/1/edit

I want to assign Id numbers for each <select> options. But I couldn't figured how.

Comment: Step 1: Create a new variable, which is an array of IDs `var idList = this.api().column(0).data().toArray();`. Step 2: Use that new array: `$('<select id="' + idList[idx] + '" >' + options + ...`. (In the future you should ask this as a new question, so the entire community can help you.)